# How to avoid function duplication

Tags: android, kotlin

Lets's say i've this function:

```
fun createView(binding, type) {
    binding.heading_text.text = type
}
```

And I need this exact function in 2 or more fragments, how can I handle this without duplicate the function every fragment?

Comment: Since that function has nothing to do with a fragment, perhaps make it a top-level function (outside of any class), or make it a function on some `companion object`.

Comment: @commonsWare I updated the question to reflect my situation, the function is responsible for createing a specifc view, and beacuse of that the function need specific fragment realated paramaters

Comment: If `binding` is the same data type in all three cases, perhaps make it an extension function on that data type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use utility static class, something like

```
class MyLogger {
    companion object {
        fun logNumbers(num1, num2) {
            Log.i("MainScreen", "${num1 + num2}")
        }
    }
}

MyLogger.logNumbers(1, 2)
```

or [inline](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) them

Comment: Sorry for my late update, but check the question I updated it. I tried what you suggest, the problem is the function accept binding object, and each fragment has different binding object

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with this function.

```
object Util {
    fun createView(binding, type) {
        binding.heading_text.text = type
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Util.createView(binding, type)
```